# How to change button label on click?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, button

When I click on this button,I want label to change. HTML:

```
<button pButton type="button" label="Edit" (click) = "foo()" style="width:auto"></button>
```

**For example** : before - "Edit", click, after - "Save".

Comment: Did you try to use `[attr.label]`?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply bind it to your component variable inside your `<button>` tag.

> ```
> <button pButton type="button" (click)="foo()"> style="width:auto">
>      {{myLabel}}
> </button>
> ```

and in your component class:

> ```
> @Component({
>   templateUrl:'./mytemplate'
> })
> export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
>   myLabel:string;
>
>   ngOnInit() {
>     this.myLabel = 'Edit';
>   }
>   foo() {
>     this.myLabel = 'Save';
>   }
> }
> ```

Here is a working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/8TOn8oN63pgJ7eA7h7tY?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

In your component class

```
@Component({
  templateUrl:'./mytemplate'
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  myLabel:string;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myLabel = 'Edit';
  }

  foo() {
    this.myLabel = 'Save';
  }
}
```

In your html

```
<button pButton type="button" [attr.label]="myLabel" (click)="foo()" style="width:auto"></button>
```

Note that the html syntax has changed to start using property binding, where the "label" attribute of the node associated with the button element is being updated with the value of the myLabel variable in the component.

Read more about template and property bindings in this guide
https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding

As a side note, if your requirement is to change the text displayed on the button, I would use interpolation as below

```
<button pButton type="button" (click)="foo()" style="width:auto">{{myLabel}}</button>
```

See this plunkr for a working example https://plnkr.co/edit/wEXKxP88kcsLKuBcUUxZ?p=preview

Comment: This will fail, becaus you missed the context for label it has to be `this.myLabel` inside the ngOnInit and Foo. I would leave out the ngOnInit and set the default value to 'Edit' on initialization: `public myLabel: string = 'Edit'`.

Comment: That is correct, I had missed the "this.". Very well spotted. Regarding the ngOnInit, the angular team recommends that any initialization for a component should be done in ngOnInit. Now for this case, it is trivial and can be either hardcoded as you mentioned or set in the constructor. I've used ngOnInit for best practice purposes (especially if the component does more than that)

Comment: Also `[label]` won't work, you have to use `[attr.label]`.

Comment: @JeanPaulA. , Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can bind attributes via `[attr.myAttribute]` directive and as in your case you have to use `[attr.label]` to bind a value to the label attribute.

Inside your component you can define a label property which gets toggled on click:

```
 class MyComponent {
    private labelStates = ['Edit', 'Save'];
    public label: string = this.labelStates[0];

    public toggleLabel() {
       let index = +(this.label === this.labelStates[0]);
       this.label = this.labelStates[index];
    }
 }
```

And use it for your button:

```
<button [attr.label]="label" (click)="toggleLabel()"></button>
```

In case you want to change the button text use this:

```
<button (click)="toggleLabel()">{{ label }}</button>
```

Comment: it wont work because label is not a property of the button.

Comment: He wants to set the label attribute and that's what this one is doing?

Comment: See the case for changing the button text. That's not what you stated in your question but i think it's what you want.

Comment: As I understand, he wants to change the button text.

Comment: Yeah but in his question he's asking to change the `label` and in his example there's a label attribute on the button.

Comment: @cyrix Works! Thank you :)